# Property 'index' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, HTMLLIElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react-typescript but on the list I have `index` but it throws a warning :

```
interface  PropsSortableElement {
  children: any;
  index: any;
  zIndex?: number;
}


export const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ children, index, zIndex }: PropsSortableElement) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <li className={classes.sortableItem} index={index} style={{ zIndex: zIndex || 1 }}>
      {children}
    </li>
  );
});
```

So I get a warning on the `index` :

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: any; className: string; index: any; style: { zIndex: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, HTMLLIElement>'.   Property 'index' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, HTMLLIElement>'.
```

How can be solved ?

Comment: Would it be an option to sort the items in javascript instead of using the `index` property?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour for the `index` property? Maybe you mean `z-index`?

Comment: `index` is not a valid attribute for `<li>` elements.